# Is there a way to pop a view controller when the user switches tabs?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, popviewcontroller

Is there a way to pop the view controller when the user switches tabs?

I have a tabbar with a navigationController on one of the tabs.  The user selects a row in a table which pushes a viewController onto the navigationController containing the table.   Then the user switches tabs to a new view.  In the new view he hits a button that brings him back to the table tab.  The problem is that the table inside the navigationController still has a view pushed onto it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the UITabBarControllerDelegate in your situation you could call:

```
[navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

when the tabbarcontroller calls it's `didSelectViewController` delegate method

Comment: I never created a class for the navigationController. I just created a navController initialized with the rootViewController, added it to the tabBar, and then released the navController. Where do I find the delegate?  Do I have to create a class for it?

Comment: Do I write navController.delegate = self;

and put didSelectViewController in the same class?

Comment: You need to set the delegate of the tabbarcontroller not the delegate of the navController. Just say `tabController.delegate = navController;` and implement the tab bar controller delegate methods in your navigation controller subclass.